Derive the expectation and variance of squared sample correlation: delta-method or else?
I would like to obtain the expectation and variance of the squared Pearson sample correlation ($\operatorname{E}(R_{lk}^2)$ and $V(R_{lk}^2)$) between two random variables $l$ and $k$ following a bivariate normal distribution.
I have been trying to trace back the results of a paper, stating that:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2)\approx R_{lk}^2 + \frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 1a}$
and thus that:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(R_{lk}^2)\approx \tilde{R}_{lk}^2 - \frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 1b}$
where $R_{lk}^2$ is the true squared correlation, $\tilde{R}_{lk}^2$ is the observed squared sample correlation and $N$ is the sample size. They claim that this result can be obtained with the $delta-method$.
My understanding of the delta-method is that one can obtain an approximate expression for the Variance of a function of a random variable, such that:
\begin{align}Var(f(X))={({f'(\mu)})^2}Var(X)&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 2a}$
Any idea how to get these results?
Derive Expected Squared Correlation Using Delta Method
Using the delta-method, I came out with this solution, but it is different from the first two equations I showed. In applying the delta-method, consider that $X=\tilde{R}$, $f(X)=\tilde{R}^2$, $f(\mu)=R_{lk}^2$ and $f'(\mu)=2R_{lk}$, where $R_{lk}$ is the true Pearson correlation.
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = {({f'(R_{lk})})^2}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk})&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 2b}$
Since $Var(\tilde{R}_{lk})$ can be interpreted as the the squared standard error of the sample correlation (Derivation of the standard error for Pearson's correlation coefficient):
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}) = \frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N - 2}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 3}$
we do get:
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = 4R_{lk}^2\frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N - 2}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 4}$
Noting that $Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = \operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2)-\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk})^2$, and the $\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk})=0$, then we obtain:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = 4R_{lk}^2\frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N - 2}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 5a}$
Derive Expected Squared Correlation Using Taylor Expansion
Instead, if I use the Taylor expansion I do get the same results as the paper. The general formula for the Taylor expansion applied to this case is (as in Expected value of inverse?):
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = R_{lk}^2+2 \frac{1}{2} Var(\tilde{R_{lk}})&\end{align}$\tag{Eq. 6}$
and again, using the standard error $Var(\tilde{R}_{lk})$ as expressed above, we get:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = R_{lk}^2+2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N - 2}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 6a}$
which by rearranging we get:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(R_{lk}^2) = \tilde{R}_{lk}^2-\frac{(1 - \tilde{R}_{lk}^2)}{N - 2}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 6b}$
Does it seem correct to you? Note that I do get the same result if I use the law of total variance (not shown here).
Derive the Variance of the Squared Correlation Using Delta Method
Regarding the variance of the sample squared correlation $Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2)$, I can apply the delta-method:
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = {({f'(R_{lk})})^2}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk})&\end{align}$\tag{Eq. 7}$
with the variance of the true correlation coefficient $R_{lk}$:
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}) = \frac{(1 - {R}_{lk}^2)^2}{N}&\end{align}$\tag{Eq. 8}$
and get
\begin{align}Var(\tilde{R}_{lk}^2) = {4R_{lk}^2} \frac{(1 - {R}_{lk}^2)^2}{N}&\end{align} $\tag{Eq. 9}$
Ultimately we could replace $R_{lk}^2$ in Eq. 9 with the expression in Eq. 6b, and obtain a formula for the variance in sample squared correlation in terms of squared sample correlation ($\tilde{R}_{lk}^2$), instead of the true squared correlation ($R_{lk}^2$).

You lost me early on, because I do not understand how "two draws each" give you anything other than a sample correlation of $1,$ $-1,$ or undefined.  Could you describe your random variables more clearly and explicitly?

Just edited my question with an explicit description of the two random variables.


I don't see how the two binomial variates are correlated at all.  2. You have the expectation of a random variable (observed squared sample correlation) being a function of the random variable itself, which doesn't make sense.


I suppose that this correspond to some adjustement, similar to what is done for the Pearson correlation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient at the section "Adjusted correlation coefficient".

The standard error of the sample correlation coefficient is approximately
$\sqrt{(1-r^2)/N}$, so the variance is just $(1-r^2)/N$, not  $(1-r^2)^2/N$ as you have in eq. 8.  Note that the answer you linked to below as a source got -1 votes and starts out with "I do not know the answer but for me there is an error in the formula...", not encouraging! Look at the Wikipedia page en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient under "Standard Error" for more information. Note also that your equation 6b is not correct.

So, I think that there is a lot of confusion in the literature in general, as you can see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196689/expected-value-and-variance-of-sample-correlation?rq=1. My understanding is that the variance is $\frac{(1-r^2)^2}{N}$, which can be approximated to $\frac{(1-r^2)}{N}$ for $r\approx 0$. Also, I was not referring to the answer with -1 vote, but the first answer with 9 votes. Also, why Eq. 6b is not correct?

With respect to 6b - you have a minus sign on the right hand side, it should be a plus sign.  To see that it can't be a minus sign, try substituting $R = 0.1$ and $N = 5$;  you'll get an expected value of $\approx -0.19$, which can't be right as the squared sample correlation must be nonnegative.  Also see my derivation below.

I see, the formula I used for the variance of the sample correlation coefficient is a useful approximation only when the correlation is small, when higher order terms are very small.  So it gets used in the most common test, that $r = 0$.

yes, it is a useful approx when $r\approx0$. Also, Eq. 6b has a negative sign in purpose. In fact, what distinguishes Eq. 6a from Eq. 6b is the rearrangement such that in Eq. 6b we have an expression for the true squared correlation in terms of sample squared correlation. Also, did you cancel your answer?

You can't express the expected value of a random variable in terms of the sample estimates, well, unless you're a Bayesian.  Furthermore, in Eq. 3 and subsequently, you express the estimator's variance in terms of the estimated value, which you can't do.  You should express it in terms of the true value.  Then, when estimating the variance, you plug in the estimated value.  But your estimate of the variance is not the same as the actual variance, which is in terms of the true values of the parameters.  Also, yes, I did cancel my answer, I may rewrite it (or maybe not).

Ok, so by reading around I seem to understand that you can express the sample variance of the correlation in terms of estimated value. In the literature there are several complicated derivations, but it appeared that the one I showed you before (considering the approx for $r\approx 0$) perform better. See Table 1 of https://osf.io/preprints/psyarxiv/uts98 for a summary of the expressions. Bonnet 2008 seems best, which is $Var(\tilde{\rho})= (1 - \tilde{\rho}^2)^2 / (N - 3)$.

That's not what's actually happening.  You estimate the sample variance of the correlation coefficient by plugging the estimated value of the correlation coefficient into the formula that was derived using the actual value of the correlation coefficient.  This is called, generically, a "plug-in estimate."   The true variance of the correlation coefficient estimator cannot, logically, be a function of the sample correlation coefficient, as every sample will return a different value but there is only one true variance.

I see your point and in fact this would make sense with the derivations of my questions by using in Eq. 6a $Var(\tilde{R})=(1 - \operatorname{E}(\tilde{R}^2))/(N -2)$ instead of  $Var(\tilde{R})=(1 - \tilde{R}^2)/(N -2)$. Still, I do not understand why they use $Var(\tilde{\rho}_i)=(1-\tilde{\rho}_i^2)^2/(N-3)$ in Bonnet 2008, where they define $\rho_i$ as the sample correlation.
